# How to use if conditions in SQL Query view

Tags: sql-server

Using view in SSMS.

I want to use if conditions in the view and add columns to the view based on conditions.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[KnowledgeArticlesJsonOut] AS
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT KA.[Id]
      ,KA.[new_brandmultiselectstring]
      ,KA.[statecode]`enter code here`
      ,KA.[statuscode]
      ,KA.[knowledgearticleid]
      ,CAT.title as categorytitle
      ,CAT.categorynumber
From [CRM].[knowledgearticle] as KA
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CRM].[knowledgearticlescategories] AS KAC on KAC.knowledgearticleid = KA.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CRM].[category] as CAT on KAC.categoryid = CAT.categoryid
GO
```

I want to add conditions like this:

1. IF KA.[new_brandmultiselectstring] contains '170001' then 170001 as
   'MRBrand'
2. IF KA.[new_brandmultiselectstring] contains '170000' then
   170000 as 'USSBrand'

in the View. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression to accomplish that as follows:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[KnowledgeArticlesJsonOut] AS
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT KA.[Id]
    , KA.[new_brandmultiselectstring]
    , KA.[statecode]
    , KA.[statuscode]
    , KA.[knowledgearticleid]
    , CAT.title AS categorytitle
    , CAT.categorynumber
    , CASE WHEN KA.[new_brandmultiselectstring] LIKE '%170001%' THEN 170001 ELSE NULL END AS MRBrand
    , CASE WHEN KA.[new_brandmultiselectstring] LIKE '%170000%' THEN 170000 ELSE NULL END AS USSBrand
FROM [CRM].[knowledgearticle] AS KA
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CRM].[knowledgearticlescategories] AS KAC ON KAC.knowledgearticleid = KA.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CRM].[category] AS CAT ON KAC.categoryid = CAT.categoryid
GO
```